# lib/tools.jar, sonarque, and jdk 11

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, java-11, tools.jar

I have a `jdk 8` full build project in jenkins that works flawlessly.  This project has a dependency on `lib/tools.jar`:

```
org.jboss.as:jboss-as-clustering-api:jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21:provided
com.sun:tools:jar:1.6:system
```

This system dependency is no problem for `jdk 8` because the `jdk` has `tools.jar` in the `lib` folder.
My `pom.xml` mentions the `jboss-as-clustering-api.jar`. It does not mention tools.jar. The project fetches
the source code and builds the project.  It runs unit tests.  It does not run sonarqube.

Next to my `jdk 8` build I created a special `jdk 11` sonarqube project. This project runs `jdk 11` because
`sonarqube 9.9` only works with a `jdk 11` or higher. The project uses the full build workspace and it only
runs sonarqube. It doesn't fetch sourcecode, doesn't build, doesn't run unit tests. It only uses maven `3.2.5` to call sonarqube:

```
-X -P full-build org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar -e --settings ${build.maven.settings} -Dsonar.projectVersion=${TARGET_SHORT_VERSION}-${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

The project fails:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project tmm: Could not resolve dependencies for project be.bpost.tmm:tmm:pom:27.30.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.6 at specified path /usr/local/post/jdk-11.0.2/../lib/tools.jar
```

How come?

I tried changing `JAVA_HOME` just before the sonarqube call so that it would point to `jdk 8` for `lib/tools`:

```
...
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/post/jdk1.8.0_72

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[TMM-MAIN-27.30-FB] $ /usr/local/post/groovy-1.7.10/bin/groovy /usr/local/post/bdf-pr/jenkins-pr2/jenkins-home/platformScripts/scripts/groovy/Sonar/prepare-qb.groovy
Artifactory integration is disabled
[TMM-MAIN-27.30-FB] $ /usr/local/post/jdk-11.0.2/bin/java -classpath /usr/local/post/apache-maven-3.2.5/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar -Dmaven.home=/usr/local/post/apache-maven-3.2.5 -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/local/post/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/m2.conf -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Dsonar.ci.url=${JOB_URL} -Dsonar.scm.url=scm:svn:http://svn.netpost:10080/svn/${ACRONYM}/${SVN_MODULE}/branches/${BRANCH_NAME} -Djava.io.tmpdir=${TEMP_DIR} -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=${HTTP_PROXY_HOST} -Dhttp.proxyPort=${HTTP_PROXY_PORT} -Dhttp.proxyUser=******** -Dhttp.proxyPassword=******** -Dhttps.proxyHost=${HTTP_PROXY_HOST} -Dhttps.proxyPort=${HTTP_PROXY_PORT} -Dhttps.proxyUser=******** -Dhttps.proxyPassword=******** -Dsonar.scm.url=scm:svn:${SVN_URL} -Dsonar.svn.username=******** -Dsonar.svn.password.secured=**** org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -f ${ACRONYM}/pom.xml -X -P full-build org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar -e --settings ${build.maven.settings} -Dsonar.projectVersion=${TARGET_SHORT_VERSION}-${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

This doesn't work. It still can't find `lib/tools.jar`. What do I have to do to make sonarqube find this dependency?
Googling gives me many results, but they all talk about using maven profiles to seperate the build and the sonarqube run.
I already seperated the build and sonarqube.  Do I have to use an exclude on tools.jar in my pom file together with a maven
profile so that the pom excludes tools.jar when it's on `jdk 11` and includes it in `jdk 8`? How do I do this? Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: First I would strongly recomment to use the most recent version sonar plugin: https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/sonar-maven-plugin/3.9.1.2184  also it looks like you are using an old JDk8 version as well as an old version of Maven 3.2.5...

Comment: Simple answer: it can’t find a `tools.jar` because there is no `tools.jar`. It’s not needed in JDK 11, as the classes formerly contained in `tools.jar` are now in the same place as all other JDK classes—at least those still supported.

Comment: So ok, my question, how do I tell my sonarqube project not to look for tools.jar?  If I modify the pom files to exclude it my jdk 8 will fail. Does anyone have an example?

Comment: Found it!  If tools.jar is missing, then exclude it from the artifact that depends on it in the pom.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

I added this to the pom.xml.

jdk 8 keeps on working, because it has ${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar.  The build uses jboss-as-ejb3 which depends on tools.jar, so we exclude ${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar if it cannot be found:

```
    <profile>
      <id>default-tools.jar</id>
      <activation>
        <file>
          <missing>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</missing>
        </file>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb3</artifactId>
          <version>7.5.0.Final-redhat-21</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
              <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
```